# #primary div disabling #secondary div in Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I have a weird bug in Chrome which affects a page in Wordpress.

I am using a slightly modified **Wordpress Twenty Eleven child theme**. The only modification are basically [CSS only](http://pastebin.com/hgXbVYU3), and it only contains colors / sizes mostly.

My problem however is that if I insert the **category list widget** then the whole **#secondary div becames non-clickable**, until the **#primary div is covering vertically**. It only happens in Chrome, Firefox is OK.

Can you have a look and tell me what is wrong? I think there is nothing wrong with the child theme and yet, this bug is quite serious. Is it a Webkit related bug, do you think, or just something wrong with the HTML/CSS?

[Live site](http://kek.org.hu/betonretro/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove

```
#main {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

as it caused the bug in Google Chrome.

I still don't understand why it is happening, but by removing it now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at your html code and find out that if you change the width of #primary to 70% the links on #secondary are able to ce clicked. I think maybe is something about the way of how webkit renders the page. You may want to check if it works and if it doesn't break on other browsers

Comment: But this is the standard layout (Twenty Eleven) for a thousands of websites! It must not have this bug!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  is overlapping on top of the right-hand side navigation due to the percentage widths you are using.

I would make the layout more fixed by making CSS changes to the following elements:

```
#primary {
float: left;
width: 700px;
margin-right: 25px;
}

#content {
margin: 0 34% 0 7.6%;
width: 600px;
}

#secondary {
float: right;
width: 200px;
}
```

It's not a complete solution, but its a start.

Comment: The solution was to remove min-height from #main. I don't know why it's happening, but removing it fixed it.